# Smart XLS examples?

Tags: c#, xls

I want to use the Smart XLS library for dealing with excel files in C# (particularly because it can generate charts, and it's price is significantly lower than Aspose Cells), but I can't find any good examples for it.  I just want to know how to create and modify charts, any guidance?

Comment: I don't know either product, but don't forget that the total cost is not only the license cost. Good documentation and a high usability for developers can easily justify a more expensive license.

Comment: Right, for me smart xls is $199 while the aspose cells is $899.  However, aspose has nice tutorials and good documentation while smart xls is taking a while to figure out.  It's not my money that is paying for it so perhaps I may just opt for aspose.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could be interested in [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/):

- Open Source.
- Charting capabilities.
- Very good reputation.
- Active maintenance, last release is just 3 months old.

It only work with xlsx files so if if you need to work with xls, its not an option.